# Magento2 Migration Tool - Deprecated Functionality: preg_replace(): Passing null to parameter

Tags: php, magento2, magento2.4

I`m trying to use the migration tool and I keep getting this:

Deprecated Functionality: preg_replace(): Passing null to parameter #3 ($subject) of type array|string is deprecated in /vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Handler/TruncateSuffix.php on line 93

```
public function handle(Record $recordToHandle, Record $oppositeRecord)
{
    if (!$this->canStart || !$this->getSuffix()) {
        return;
    }
    $attributeIds = $this->getAttributeIds();
    if (in_array($recordToHandle->getValue('attribute_id'), $attributeIds)) {
        $suffix = '~' . preg_quote($this->getSuffix()) . '$~';
        $value = $recordToHandle->getValue($this->field);
        $value = preg_replace($suffix, '', $value);
        $recordToHandle->setValue($this->field, $value);
    }
}
```

Already tried to apply a patch but its not working, i`m getting the same error.

```
     if (in_array($recordToHandle->getValue('attribute_id'), $attributeIds)) {
         $suffix = '~' . preg_quote($this->getSuffix()) . '$~';
         $value = $recordToHandle->getValue($this->field);
       $value = preg_replace($suffix, '', $value);
       if ($value !== null)
          $value = preg_replace($suffix, '', $value);
         $recordToHandle->setValue($this->field, $value);
     }
 }
```

Any thoughts?